# Image caching not in List View android

Tags: java, android, image, caching

Hi guys i am stuck with image caching. i need to populate Linear Layout with images from web.

I was searching examples how to cache images in android and found these examples:

- http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html
- [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)

I tried it implement for my code.

```
    String picPath = "https://www.google.lt/logos/classicplus.png";

    try {
        /*
        View v = null;//new View(this);

        ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(this);
        ImageView im = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.image);

        loader.DisplayImage(picPath, im);
        addImage( im);*/

          LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ImageDownloader down = new ImageDownloader();
        down.download(picPath, image);
        addImage(image);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    public void addImage( View view){

        LinearLayout pubLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById( R.id.scrollerLinearlayout);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //setting layout_margin
        params.setMargins(15, 30, 15, 30);
        pubLayout.addView(view,params);

}
```

However this didn't worked. I believe because i add view to linear layout and when image is downloaded it can't repaint it ?

There are examples how to do image caching using ListView. But what to do if i am not using List View.

I would write my own caching but how to make callback to image downloaded as i want first add image to layout and on callback update it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call invalidate on parent view

```
    pubLayout.getParent().invalidate();
```

Comment: When i should call this ? And my publyaout which is linearlayout don't have invalidate(); just
invalidateChild(child, r) and invalidateChildInParent(location, r)

Comment: this sounds weird. My LinearLayouts do have invalidate. :\                 which version of Android are you using...

Comment: This isn't what i wanted so it would be wrong to accept an answer as others wouldn't find it useful. I guess

Comment: I appreciate your help. Sorry for your time